# Player controls element not visible when declaring container-type as inline-size to use Container query

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web page that includes a video player, and I'm trying to position the player controls using CSS. However, I'm encountering an issue where the player controls element is not visible when I declare container-type: inline-size for the parent container.

Here's the relevant HTML and CSS code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .video {
        width: 100vw;
      }
      .player-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 56.25%; /* Player ratio: 100 / (1280 / 720) */
        font-size: 1rem;
      }
      .player-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 3cqw;

        container-type: inline-size;
        container-name: player-wrapper;
      }
      .player-controls {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
      }
      .iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
      }
      .name {
        width: 50cqw;
        height: 10cqw;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="video">
      <div class="player-wrapper">
        <div class="player-overlay">
          <div class="player-controls">
            <div class="name">Aditya</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="iframe"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, I have a player-controls element inside a player-overlay element, which is within a player-wrapper element. The player-overlay element has the following styles: position: absolute;, display: flex;, justify-content: center;, align-items: center;, font-size: 3cqw;, container-type: inline-size;, container-name: player-wrapper;.

However, when I include container-type: inline-size; for the player-overlay element, the player-controls element becomes invisible. If I remove that line, the controls become visible again.

What could be causing this issue? Is there a conflict between the container-type property and the visibility of the child elements? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!